# Python "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed" raised only when code is written in a funciton

Tags: python, pandas, hash, multiprocessing, typeerror

I'm writing a function that needs to use multiprocessing to make calculations on data stored in a pandas.DataFrame. The code looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool

def foo(data_frame):
    #do stuff

def bar(data_frame, n)
    pool = Pool(n)
    result = pool.map(foo, data_frame)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return result

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(<data>, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

#because Pool.map() requires a list of arguments as the 2nd argument:
df_aslist = [data_frame.iloc[i] for i in range(len(data_frame))]
bar(data_frame=df_aslist, n=5)
```

When I run the code I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

But if I were to write the code inside bar() outside the function like so:

```
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(<data>, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df_aslist = [data_frame.iloc[i] for i in range(len(data_frame))]
pool = Pool(n)
result = pool.map(foo, df_aslist)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The code runs without errors. My question is why? And also how can I fix the issue for when I write it in a function bar()?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I'll provide more details to give a better understanding of my example.
The purpose of my program is to take pairs of lat-lon coordinates and calculate the distance and duration between them. The pairs of coordinates is what data_frame is containing, so it looks more like this:

```
data_frame = pd.DataFrame({
    'loc1lon' : loc1lon_list,
    'loc1lat' : loc1lat_list,
    'loc2lon' : loc2lon_list,
    'loc2lat' : loc2lat_list
})
```

The distance is being calculated with libOSRM, the backend library that OSRM (Open Source Routing Machine) uses to make routing calculations. It is a C++ library, so I used Boost::Python to write a simple module that can use libOSRM (I named the module PyOSRM :P). I use it in my program like so:

```
import PyOSRM
def foo(data):
    #foo is defined as a trick to allow multiprocessing to be used on boost::python funcitons. Would not work otherwise.
    return PyOSRM.calculate_loc_data(data)
```

Comment: You are so close to providing a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... why not include a way for viewers of your question to reproduce `<data>` and `foo` such that we can recreate your problem?

Comment: With `data = np.random.rand(10,4)` and `def foo(data_frame): return data_frame` I am able to execute your function example with no errors.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. But I don't think viewers can reacreate my exact scenario because foo involves using fucntions from a C++ library I wrote with Boost::Python. However I will edit my question to give more context :)

Comment: Without being able to reproduce the error, it's hard to figure out what could be going on. A longer stack trace would also help that shows the source of the error.

Comment: The stack trace shows that pool.map() is what causes the error